# Android won't refresh background image when installing/building App

Tags: android, eclipse, background-image

I have a very strange situation.
My background image of the layout won't change when I rebuild/reinstall the app on the phone.

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/logout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@raw/image_new"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my case I had before image "image_new" another image that loaded ok. Then I changed it and I had this problem that the image didn't change when I rebuild/reinstalled the app, but then somehow I get it changed. Now that I changed the image again, I have a white (empty) background.

I Cleaned the project 10x times, I restarted Eclipse 3 times, I un-installed the app from the phone and still nothing. The background is white. But in Eclipse the layout looks ok -> the image (the background) is there.

What am I missing? Is there some kind of a bug or what?

Comment: USe drawable folder, not raw folder to store your images.

Comment: Ok I put the image in all drawable folder (hdpi,ldpi,..), because if I putted the image only in "drawable" folder it didn't work. But now the background image in un-sharp. How can it be un-sharped if has the same resolution as my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini?